# how to pull the first tweets of an account?

Tags: python-3.x, twitter, tweepy

I want to pull the first tweets made by an account. 
In other words, I want to retrieve the first 1000 tweets an account has twitted since it first opened the account. In my case, the twitter account is NASA, which is created at `(2007, 12, 19, 20, 20, 32)`

I have tried `api.user_timeline` but it retrieves the most reccent tweets.I also added`since_id` .

```
tweets = api.user_timeline("NASA", since_id =1, count=20)
```

but I get the most recent tweets again. I  assume I have not used `since_id` correctly. 
How can I retrieve the first tweets made by NASA?

Comment: [The docs](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/v3.5.0/api.html#API.user_timeline) say *"20 most recent"*; `since_id` will only act to drop the slightly older ones you've already seen. Have a look at e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58356783/how-to-pull-the-first-tweets-of-an-account

Comment: So, can you think of a solution?

Comment: You would need to use the full-archive historical search API (premium) to go back as far as 2007 for that account.

Comment: @Andy Piper I assume it is paid, right? Is there a free way?

Comment: Not that I am aware of, no.